# JSTL c:catch JSF equivalent

Tags: jsf, jstl

I try to convert a JSP tag to its JSF equivalent. In the JSP file I found a `c:catch` block.

The `c:` comes from `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" prefix="c" %>`.

In JSF I have the XML namespace `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`.

Can I use `c:catch` also in JSF or is there another JSF equivalent to do the same thing?

Comment: Exceptions in theory including JSP should be handled in Java code - converters/validators, managed beans/DAO/EJBs, if needed at all but not on XHTML/JSP(X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) core. It catches any `Throwable` that occurs in its body and optionally exposes it. Simply it is used for error handling. Check the documentation:

- [c:catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/)

However, mixing JSF and JSTL is problematic. Facelets brings limited support for `<c:if>` `<c:forEach>` `<c:catch>` `<c:set>`

See also:

- [Java Server Faces Exception Handling and Formatting](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/jsf-2-exception-handling-and-formatting)